# AB Testing on Microsoft Store

Tags: windows, uwp, ab-testing

Is it possible to test different icons, description, etc. **on store** (Microsoft Store)? On ios, google, it is possible to test different icons and other elements for the application in the store. *On UWP has not yet found*. Can this be done at all? What tools are there for this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's customer service-related and not a specific programming question. We can't answer questions about off-site app stores or services. Contact that vendor's customer service department to ask them what is and isn't available to you. In addition, questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries or other off-site resources are off-topic according to the [site guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a issue in developer dashboard, the ms stuff will help u.